# Error CS1729: The type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a constructor that takes `5' arguments

Tags: c#, list, constructor, compiler-errors

I'm learning C and C#, this question is for C#. This problem is code from a book, and the code doesn't compile, the error is:Error CS1729: The type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a constructor that takes`5' arguments.

Here is the code:

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>("Christa ",
                                          "  Sarah",
                                          "Jonathan",
                                          "Sam",
                                          " Schmekowitz");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `(` and `)` to `{` and `}`.

I.e.

```
List<string> names = new List<string>{"Christa ",
                                      "  Sarah",
                                      "Jonathan",
                                      "Sam",
                                      " Schmekowitz"};
```

Answer (score 4):

Correct `List` initialization syntax uses braces:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Christa ",
                                      "  Sarah",
                                      "Jonathan",
                                      "Sam",
                                      " Schmekowitz" };
```